# Issued certificate does not show issuer details

Tags: java, security, ssl, x509certificate, bouncycastle

In my Application I am creating a certificate and signing with a self signed CA. from code I can see all the details such as issuer details, validity. 
But Issued certificate does not show issuer details when see it in windows Certificate explorer under "Certification path" tab. what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

```
public void issueCertificate(KeyPair keypair, String cn, int days,
        KeyPurposeId purposeId) throws Exception {

    if (keypair != null) {
        this.issuedKeyPair = keypair;
    } else {
        this.issuedKeyPair = generateRSAKeyPair();
    }

    PKCS10CertificationRequest request = generateCSR(issuedKeyPair, cn);

    X509V3CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

    certGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    certGen.setIssuerDN(caCertificate.getSubjectX500Principal());
    certGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    certGen.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * days)));
    certGen.setSubjectDN(request.getCertificationRequestInfo().getSubject());
    certGen.setPublicKey(request.getPublicKey("BC"));
    certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");

    certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier, false,
            new AuthorityKeyIdentifierStructure(caCertificate));
    certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier, false,
            new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(request.getPublicKey("BC")));
    certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.BasicConstraints, true,
            new BasicConstraints(false));
    certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(
            KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment));
    certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, true,
            new ExtendedKeyUsage(purposeId));

    ASN1Set attributes = request.getCertificationRequestInfo()
            .getAttributes();

    if (attributes != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i != attributes.size(); i++) {
            org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.Attribute attr = org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.Attribute
                    .getInstance(attributes.getObjectAt(i));

            if (attr.getAttrType().equals(
                    PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest)) {
                X509Extensions extensions = X509Extensions.getInstance(attr
                        .getAttrValues().getObjectAt(0));

                Enumeration e = extensions.oids();
                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    DERObjectIdentifier oid = (DERObjectIdentifier) e
                            .nextElement();
                    X509Extension ext = extensions.getExtension(oid);

                    certGen.addExtension(oid, ext.isCritical(), ext
                            .getValue().getOctets());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.issuedCertificate = certGen.generate(caKeyPair.getPrivate());

}
```

Comment: Did you actually sign your certificate with a CA?  My guess is no.  Another guess is that you will actually need to sign the certificate with a CA to get the "Certification path".

Comment: Yes. I finally figured it out what was the actual issue. RootCA needs to be there in trust store. thanks for response.